# grunt-contrib-coffee source map only points to joined file

Tags: node.js, dictionary, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm using Grunt to compile my project, and I'm very happy with it. However, when I attempt to create source maps for my CoffeeScript-files, `grunt-contrib-coffee` generates a map to the joined file (the concatenated result of all my CoffeeScript files), not to my actual CoffeeScript sources, and I have been unable to find a reason for this.

How do I make the compiler generate a map of my actual CoffeeScript sources, instead of the joined file?

After CoffeeScript has compiled, I use `grunt-contrib-uglify` to generate the actually-used JS file, and its `sourceMapIn`-option is working like a charm. It's the CoffeeScript compiler that generates a weird source map.

Here's my `grunt-contrib-coffee`-configuration. The `app-files` contains an array of 24 CoffeeScript files.

```
{
  "source": {
    "options": {
      "bare": true,
      "sourceMap": true
    },
    "expand": true,
    "join": true,
    "cwd": ".",
    "ext": ".js",
    "files": {
      "<%= build_dir %>/public.js": [ "<%= app_files.coffee %>" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the resulted source map.

```
{
 "version": 3,
 "file": "public.js",
 "sourceRoot": "",
 "sources": [
   "public.src.coffee"
 ],
  "names": [],
  "mappings": [ ... ]
}
```

As you see, the only source it points to is `public.src.coffee`, which is the file CoffeeScript joined my files into before compiling into CS.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure that the source map concerns the joined coffee file, and not the compiled javascript source? Source maps are there to make joined & minified javascript files more readable. This would not make sense for coffeescript, as you cannot minify it...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, frhd. You are right in that it's a JS-sourcemap, but what happens is that when I've just run my Grunt "Coffee"-task, the "public.src.coffee"-file is generated (joined by the compiler), and a JS-sourcemap to it is created - but the only source file the map points to the "public.src.coffee"-file (the joined one). I'd like it to point to my actual CoffeeScript-files, like my own "SsnValidator"-class etc. Why does the "sources"-property contain only the ".src.coffee"-file instead of "EmailValidator.coffee" etc? This is what's strange.